# Log4J creates log file but does not write to it

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm trying to configure log4j to log messages to a file. Right now, the file does get created with the name I provide, but the logs are not written to the file.  My code:

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( Main.class.getName() );
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        logger.warning("test");
        logger.severe("oh noes");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Contents of my `log4j.properties` file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1024MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

When I run this, I get this output in the console:

```
Jun 23, 2014 3:19:16 AM com.foo.Main start
WARNING: test
Jun 23, 2014 3:19:16 AM com.foo.Main start
SEVERE: oh noes
```

The file `log.log` does get created in my main directory. But its empty.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm using log4j version 1.2.17.

Comment: Are you sure you're importing Log4J's `Logger` class, and not `java.util.logging.Logger`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The output seems to be of the default format that Java's standard logging framework (JUL) would emit.

So, there are two possibilities (that come to mind):

1. Your code imports `java.util.logging.Logger`, rather than `org.apache.log4j.Logger`.
2. There exists a library of some sort, in your classpath, that intercepts Log4J calls and converts them to JUL calls.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. But I'm noticing that only my `error` or higher messages are logged to file or to console. Any ideas how to get it to log all levels?

Comment: The way that your configuration is set (perhaps you had changed it since posting it here?), Log4J will only print messages which are `info` and up, and it will print them to both console and file. You can change this behaviour by changing `INFO` to `ALL` in `log4j.rootLogger`. If that doesn't work, add `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to your JVM arguments - that will make Log4J emit debug messages about itself (to System.out), so you can see what's going on.

Comment: If it's scenario #2, is there a way to identify who brought in the interceptor, and what is the recommended way to amend it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you. File was created, but without any logs in it just in console. And it was because of incorrect dependencies in maven project in my case.

My `log4j.properties` file was:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
# configuration to print into file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log\\logging.log
# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.file.Append=false
```

And I used in POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
    
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Yes, it created for me file where I needed it, but logs were in console. Then I changed it to another dependency like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And I finally got it in file instead of console. Even without any explicit commands like `PropertyConfigurator.configure()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and i solved it.
When I changed level form INFO to DEBUG in properties file - line:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file, stdout
```

and than I wrote in script:

`logger.debug("Hello world");`

everything was saved in file.

Answer (score -1):

### FILE NAME HERE IS ACTUALLY THE PACKAGE OF THE LOGGER CLASS

logger.file.name="your package name in java"