# Log4j2.xml doesn't create file suddenly in java hibernate framework

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, log4j2

I have a maven project in NetBeans with hibernate framework. For a long time it was doing its job correctly. After some modification in database, console log is still working but writing to file has stopped without any error or exception. I have deleted log file directory and restart project, but this time it couldn't even create file path directory.
here is my log4j2.xml configuration(in src/main/resources)

I have changed path to D:\logs and D:/logs, and tried different levels (debug, info, error). Also tried to run my "Server.jar" from command line by administrator. And it should be mentioned that I tried the solution in [Log4J creates log file but does not write to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356319/log4j-creates-log-file-but-does-not-write-to-it) and lots of other suggested solutions, but no success achieved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="path">${sys:user.home}/logs/server</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders >
        <RollingFile name="connections"  append="true"  fileName="${path}/connections.log"
                     filePattern="${path}/connections-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" >
            <!-- log pattern -->
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern> %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  [%-4level] - %msg %n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <!-- set file size policy -->
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>        
        <RollingFile name="unexpected-events"  append="true"  fileName="${path}/unexpected-events.log"
                     filePattern="${path}/unexpected-events-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" >
            <!-- log pattern -->
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern> %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  [%-4level] - %msg %n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <!-- set file size policy -->
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="readouts"  append="true"  fileName="${path}/readouts.log"
                     filePattern="${path}/readouts-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log" >
            <!-- log pattern -->
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern> %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}  [%-4level] - %msg %n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <!-- set file size policy -->
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>        
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="connections" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="connections" level="debug"/>
            <!--<appender-ref ref="console-log" level="debug"/>-->
        </Logger>                
        <Logger name="unexpected-events" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="unexpected-events" level="debug"/>
            <!--<appender-ref ref="console-log" level="debug"/>-->
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="readouts" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="readouts" level="debug"/>
            <!--<appender-ref ref="console-log" level="debug"/>-->
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error" additivity="false">
            <!--<AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>-->
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

and this is how I used it in my java class:

```
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

    ......

    private static final Logger connectionsLog = LogManager.getLogger("connections");

    ....
     connectionsLog.info("device" + deviceNumber + " disconnected");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By special thanks to user944849 , I understood that the problem could be related to maven dependencies. Then I checked previous version of my project (which has correct logging) and compare dependencies and found out that a library "log4j-to-slf4j" is added (which has added because of importing "org.springframework.boot"). Then first I exclude it from dependency in pom.xml file, as a result it worked fine in NetBeans IDE but not out of it. Then I removed that dependency from pom.xml and problem solved like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen weirdness like this when both `commons-logging` and `jcl-over-slf4j` are on the classpath together. Excluding `commons-logging` from the Maven classpath, anywhere it appears, often helps.